# Joomla article not being published

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Well I have this weird issue. I have a joomla website and everytime I do any changes and then apply those changes, the website is updated. Everything goes fine . However after few hours .. say usually 24 hours, the changes are reverted back to their original form (i.e exactly like before the changes).

I recently updated joomla to 1.5.25 from 1.5.21. Can this update be the reason?

Comment: are ou the only person with access to the system? And is you hosting provider not just putting backups back?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be one of a number of things:

1) Your hosting provider is restoring your Joomla database which is in effect reverting your articles

2) Someone has hacked your Joomla installation and is messing with your head. This is very unlikely though so do not panic